# HTML input sanitizing: reasonable to replace single quote ' with right single quote ’ for name field in DB?

Tags: html, replace, storage, quote, sanitize

E.g., D'Arcy becomes D’Arcy.

It appears that both Bing and Google process ’ the same way as '. If this is so, is there any functional reason to not sanitize a name field with respect to the single quote by replacing it with the single right quote before saving it into the DB? Thus saving having to encode it each time it is displayed on an HTML page?

Comment: Apart from the fact that users get narky when you transform data they enter - most particularly usernames, probably not. If it's something they'll type in again, you'll have to convert it again. Personally, I prefer to store data as entered, transforming for display purposes as needed. This prevents data loss. I can transform the data 'forwards' anytime I like. But if I change it, it's quite likely that I can't reliably transform it back again. A Perfect case in point are names. You can't just capitalize the first letter of each word - it's not always correct.

Comment: @enhzflep, if they are functionally interchangable in print, and if a single quote is just a poor man's single right quote in all cases in a name, then it would appear fine and there would be functionally no data lost. If that were not the case, then that would be one problem with it. Perhaps someone will identify this as an actual problem. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: Grrrr! So you're one of the people that makes 'harmless' changes to entered data because you don't feel like escaping/unescapaing it. The number of times I've copied and pasted code only to find that some jack-ass has changed the quote characters to ones my compiler/interpreter simply baulks at. As long as it only 'seems okay', it's not good enough. You should be able to prove that it does/can not have a detrimental effect. I really hate it when the substitute is a char that's not on my keyboard. Sometimes, the only thing one can do is try over and over to compile - fix 1 error per cycle.